# Error en Foreground

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo un problema con mi aplicación android, tengo el problema de startForeground me marca un error, pero solo me ocurre en Android 10. les dejo el error que me marca en logCat...

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground
```

Esto me pasa cuando minimizo la aplicación (onPause) y tengo un proceso de impresión en segundo plano, y cuando regreso a ella (onResume) me tira ese error y me saca de la aplicación, cabe mencionar que no tengo ningún servicio de notificaciones, lo cual se me hace bastante raro. Pero si tengo Robospice para ejecutar el servicio de impresion en segundo plano con la version:

```
'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14'
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para dispositivos con API 28 (android 9.0) requieres definir en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

> Cambio:
> **Permiso de servicios en primer plano.**
>
> Las apps que intenten usar servicios en primer plano ahora deben
> solicitar primero el permiso `FOREGROUND_SERVICE`. Este es un permiso
> normal, de modo que el sistema se lo otorga automáticamente a la app
> que lo solicita. El inicio de un servicio en primer plano sin el
> permiso genera una SecurityException.

Revisa:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration

Comment: Si lo tengo agregado amigo, ya esta preevisto ese permiso.